# PostgreSQL Match any strings

Tags: postgresql

I have a SQL query:

```
select recipe_title
             from recipe where
             meal_type ='BREAKFAST'
```

Is it possible to match any meal_type by only change the `BREAKFAST`?

```
Such as:
    select recipe_title
                 from recipe where
                 meal_type = *
```

I know I can use `like %%` but that will need to change many places in my code. Is it possible to get all  meal_type and still use `=`

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `?` in the question a placeholder or just that you want use the `=` operator? Can you expand how this is being used in your code?

Comment: I just want to use  = operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `=` is an equality operator. The best you can do is [`WHERE meal_type = ANY('{BREAKFAST,LUNCH,DINNER}')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16), iff you have a known short list of all possible values, but there's no wildcard-like behavior with `=`. The correct way of doing this (returning all rows regardless of `meal_type`) is to not have a `meal_type = <whatever>` in your WHERE clause.